# Можно ли создать "составную" переменную в c#. Например состоящую из byte,byte,string,string

Tags: c#

```
list<(string,string,byte,byte)> ???
```

Чтоб к каждому члену этого списка соотвецвовало 2 переменные byte и 2 string

Смотрел в сторону Dictionary, но там только 2 переменные, мне 4 нужно как минимум

Comment: создайте свой класс с тремя полями и делайте список этого класса

Answer (score -1):

1. Это называется `Tuple<string, string, byte, byte>`
2. В C# можно делать так

   ```
   var t = new List<(string, string, byte, byte)>(); 
   t.Add(("one", "two", 3, 4));
   ```

Comment: У вас первая часть не соответствует второй. `(string, string, byte, byte)` и `Tuple<string, string, byte, byte>` - это как бы разные классы.

Comment: @PavelMayorov так я два варианта для этого и показал, но спасибо за замечание, давайте явно это пропишу.

Answer (score -1):

Как то так можно сделать

```
namespace Triple
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");


            var v = new Triple<object, List<string>, string, int>();

            v.Add(1, null, "", 4);
        }
    }



    public class Triple<T1, T2, T3, T4>
    {
        private List<Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4>> values;


        public Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4> this[int index]
        {
            get => values[index];
            set => values[index] = value;
        }

        public Triple()
        {
            values = new List<Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4>>();
        }

        public void Add(T1 value1, T2 value2, T3 value3, T4 value4)
        {
            values.Add(new Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4>(value1, value2, value3, value4));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MyData {
public string Field1 {get; set;}
public string Field2 {get; set;}
public byte Field3 {get; set;}
public byte Field4 {get; set;}
}


List<MyData> data = new List<MyData> { new MyData { Field1 = "name", Field2 = "description", Field3 = 0, Field4 = 1}};
```